# Efficient way to create a new array by matching values of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array `$_SESSION['Products']` which comes from a database:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [entity_id] => 1 [sku] => 0001 ) 
[1] => Array ( [entity_id] => 2 [sku] => 0002 ) 
)
```

And this list `$data` which comes from a txt file (see while loop below):

```
Array ( [0] => 0001 [1] => ABC [2] => 0 [3] => 1.0000 [4] => 25.9400 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0002 [1] => CDE [2] => 0 [3] => 1.0000 [4] => 28.6600 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0003 [1] => EFG [2] => 0 [3] => 1.0000 [4] => 30.9900 )
```

I need to match `sku` from `$_SESSION['Products']` with `[0]` from `$data` and add `entity_id` on match.

This is what I have so far and it's working:

```
//read txt file
do {
    $line = fgets($handle);
    
    if ($line !== false) {
        //explode data
        $data = explode(";", $line);
    }

    foreach ($_SESSION['Products'] as $p) {
        if ($p["sku"] === $data[0]) {
            $data[5] = $p["entity_id"];
        }
    }
} while ($line !== false);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 0001 [1] => ABC [2] => [3] => 1.0000 [4] => 25.9400 [5] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 0002 [1] => CDE [2] => [3] => 1.0000 [4] => 28.6600 [5] => 2 ) 
)
```

The big issue is **performance**, though. `$_SESSION['Products']` can have up to 7k entries where as `$data` has 10k lines. (Actually I also need to match another array into it, which makes it even slower, obviously). The script runs but the browser keeps loading for one minute. Unfortunately I need to do it in the browser.

Is there any much more efficient way?

Comment: That's why databases do exist.

Comment: You will need to use the database for this.

Comment: I was thinking about putting the txt file into a database first but then I also need to do it via browser unfortunately. Which isn't much more efficient.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. Databases are quicker than what you have described. What does a browser have to do with the way the data is processed? Also, a good part of your issue may lie in *rendering* the result. Are you really showing 7-10k entries on a page?

Comment: Ok, suggestions are: Putting the txt file into the database, fetch all data, build the new array and (this is what I forgot to mention), put the result into a database. <- that's the final goal. It's not possible to match everything via DB and put the end result into a table, isn't it?

Comment: It might be possible, since you say that your session values come from the database. If everything was in the database, it could possibly be solved completely through queries, but then you'd have to expand on your example to show exactly what is expected from this process.

Comment: Basically I need to match sku from txt (which would be table A then) and table B (which holds the entity_id). The entity_id needs to go into table C together with the price (which is [4] in the example above, but would then also come from table A). I think I could figure out the exact query. I just need a basic idea on how that query could look like. Would it be done with (some) JOIN statements and coping over the corresponding rows ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data structure you could potentially get rid of the inner `foreach` which will save some processing time by normalizing your `$_SESSION` data first:

```
//create array with index = sku
$productSession = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['Products'] as $p) {
    $productSession[$p['sku']] = $p;
}
  
//read txt file
do {
    $line = fgets($handle);
    
    if ($line !== false) {
        //explode data
        $data = explode(";", $line);
    }

    if (isset($productSession[$data[0]])) { //check for array key instead of a foreach
        $data[5] = $productSession[$data[0]]["entity_id"];
    }

} while ($line !== false);
```

The `isset()` will be much faster than looping 7k products for every line in the csv but as others suggested a database will be much better.

Comment: Thanks, something like is what I was looking for, at least I will try and also compare it to a database solution.